# Correct use of Lucene BooleanQuery?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to nest one BooleanQuery inside of another.

The inner BooleanQuery is created with the following code and added to topBQuery.

```
    BooleanQuery topBQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    // add a numeric range query on loan amount.
    if( row.getLoan_amt() > 0 ){
        BooleanQuery loanBQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        Double loanMin = 0.0;
        Double loanMax = 0.0;
        Double loanAmt = row.getLoan_amt();
        // Range should be within +- 5% of loan amount.
        loanMin = loanAmt - (loanAmt * .05);
        loanMax = loanAmt + (loanAmt * .05);

        loanBQuery.add(NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(TitleRecordColumns.SR_LOAN_VAL_1.toString(), loanMin, loanMax, true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        loanBQuery.add(NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(TitleRecordColumns.SR_LOAN_VAL_2.toString(), loanMin, loanMax, true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        loanBQuery.add(NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(TitleRecordColumns.SR_LOAN_VAL_3.toString(), loanMin, loanMax, true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

        topBQuery.add(loanBQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }
```

Another field is added to topBQuery with the following:

```
    if( !row.getPropertykey_tx().isEmpty() ){
        //TitleRecordColumns is an enum
        topBQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(TitleRecordColumns.SA_SITE_ADDR.toString(), row.getPropertykey_tx())), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
```

I only want documents that match the ranges I've created in any of the SR_LOAN_VAL fields. A record should also match the provided address. Am I creating the BooleanQuery properly?

Is there also a better way to do this kind of search?

I'm using Lucene 4.7. I've looked at my index with Luke and I am confident that I've indexed the fields properly. Thank you!

Edit:

This is the code I am using to generate the "final query" that I use to search the index with. Most examples I've seen do something like this. Is this correct?

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
Query finalQuery = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_47, TitleRecordColumns.SA_SITE_ADDR.toString(), analyzer).parse(topBQuery.toString());
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopDocs results = searcher.search(finalQuery, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks reasonable to me.

When you say that A record *"should"* also match the address, it is not clear what you mean though.  If you mean that all results *Must* match the address, then you should change the Occur argument when adding that subquery to `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST`.  If you mean that it is preferred to have a match on that field, and you want to see those documents at the top, but anything matching the numeric range queries is an acceptable result, then your current query is correct.

Comment: One of the numeric ranges needs to match first and then an address needs to match. Does that clarify? Either way, you're saying the query looks good. My lack of results probably indicates that the data is just not in my index.

Comment: @Cuthbert, I propose you to add last term query as Occur.MUST

Comment: @Cuthbert - Yes, as I said, if the address must match, `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST` is the correct argument.  I wasn't aware you were getting no results though.  There is nothing inherantly wrong about your usage of BooleanQueries, and changing that `Occur` value will certainly not cause you to get more results.  I suspect you are indexing the fields in such a way that you are getting no results.  Are you using a `DoubleField` to index the loan amount fields?  Are the field names correct (they are case sensitive!)?  Is the address analyzed or not?

Comment: They're indexed with `IntField`. I realized this might be a problem so I'm converting my doubles to ints.

Comment: Why aren't you using `NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange`?

Comment: The data that I was trying to search with has its values stored as doubles. But the data that was indexed had its values stored as Integers.

Comment: You will need to use the same type at index and query time.  If you index an `IntField`, query with `NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange`.  If you need to query with doubles, cast your ints to doubles, and index a `DoubleField`.  Try that, and test with simpler queries.  I suspect you may run into a disconnect on how you are handling addresses, so just make sure you can get results from a single RangeQuery on an amount field, and then increase the complexity.

Comment: @femtoRgon I've made the changes you suggested and looked in the debugger and noticed that after I parse my Boolean query with the standard analyzer, the output of that contains a TermRangeQuery and not a NumericRangeQuery. Is this expected behavior? Does that matter? I'm still not getting the results I expect.

Comment: Yes, it's expected behavior, QueryParser doesn't support generating `NumericRangeQuery`.  Yes, it matters, one matches lexicographically, the other numerically, and is stored in a "prefix coded" format. If you need to handle numeric ranges in parsed queries, you'll need to subclass `QueryParser`. Simply override [QueryParser.newRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#newRangeQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)), to make a range of appropriate type for the field name.